# Why aren't awarded badges removed if the question is deleted?

Tags: discussion, badges, deleted-questions

I was looking at a badge page, in particular the [reversal badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/95/reversal) one, and noticed that the first two users earning this badge answered to question which has been deleted afterwards.

I noticed that when this happens, I mean when a question is deleted, the reputation is restored: if a user gains 10 point of rep, for example, then he/she will lose them once the corresponding question is removed. The same happens if a user loses 10 points of rep: he/she will gain them again once the question is deleted.

Why this doesn't apply to badges?

I would expect that if the corresponding question is closed, one loses the earned badge ... or this logic applies only to revival badges since it can happen that a question of -5 score might be deleted?

Comment: Badges are eternal. Once you earn one, you can't lose it.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Except for tag badges.

Comment: @YannisRizos Hmm. I did not know that. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Badges, with the exception of tag badges, aren't removed (except in cases where they have been obtained by manifest swindling).

They are awarded for an achievement, and you don't unachieve just because the question was deleted.

In particular the [Reversal](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/95/reversal) badge would be removed a lot if it weren't so.

[Nowadays](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/), even the reputation one gained doesn't necessarily vanish if the post is deleted. If the contribution was substantial enough to have a score of 3 or above, and the post was on the site for longer than 60 days, the reputation is not deleted together with the post.

Since a badge is indicative of an achievement of greater magnitude than just one upvote (in general), it makes sense to not revoke them, like the reputation gained from high-enough scoring and not too short-lived posts.

Comment: To be fair, the same argument could be made about rep. "You don't unearn rep just because the question was deleted." Just another one of the many minor inconsistencies in the system. But I don't particularly see it as an issue.

Comment: True, but nowadays you also don't unearn the rep if your contribution was received well enough to have a score of at least 3, and survived for 60 days or more.